# Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of null

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, components, emit

I am working on a vue project and want to emit an event from a child component to a parent component after some time span (user hovers over element, and after a few seconds, the emit should happen).

I am pretty sure I have done emits similar to this in other components and that it has worked before, but now I get these two errors. I am not sure what has changed. I implemented vuex after my first try, came back to this and now I am not sure what happend? But maybe I just deleted something or I don't know.
I also tried a console log just above the line that seems problematic and there the this value doesn't seem to be null. 
These are the errors I get:

**[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of null"** and after that the error **Cannot read property 'emit' of null** The first error mentions, that the error was found in the component, shown beneath.

Most stuff I saw related to this problem was about people doing es6 arrow functions incorrectly, so maybe the `this.timer = setInterval(() => this.countdown(), 1000);`is problematic? I am not quite sure.

And here is the component (please excuse the messy code):

```
<template>
    <div
        :id="id"
        class="board"
        @dragenter.prevent
        @dragover.prevent
        @drop.prevent="drop"
        @dragenter="dragenter($event)"
        @dragover="dragover($event)"
        @dragleave="dragleave($event)"
    >
        <slot class="row"/>
        <div
        :id="`ui-details-${id}`"
        v-show="extendedHover">
        Long hover
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Devices',
  props: ['id', 'acceptsDrop'],
  data() {
    return {
      extendedHover: false,
      timer: null,
      totalTime: 2,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    drop(e) {
      if (e.dataTransfer.getData('type') === 'layout') { // only accept dropped cards, not boards
        const layoutId = e.dataTransfer.getData('layout_id');
        this.$emit('dropped-layout', layoutId);
      }
      clearInterval(this.timer);
      this.timer = null;
      this.totalTime = 2;
      console.log(e.dataTransfer.getData('card_id'));
      e.target.classList.remove('hover-drag-over');
      this.extendedHover = false;
      // this.$emit('cancel-hover');
      console.log('-------------dropped');
      console.log(e);
      console.log(e.dataTransfer.getData('type'));
      /* const cardId = e.dataTransfer.getData('card_id');
      console.warn('dropped onto device');
      this.$emit('dropped-component', cardId);
      e.target.classList.remove('hover-drag-over'); */
    },
    dragenter(e) {
      // on dragenter we start a countdown of 1s
      // over this value --> we see it as a long hover
      console.log('------------dragenter');
      console.log(e);
      this.timer = setInterval(() => this.countdown(), 1000);
    },
    dragover(e) {
      if (this.acceptsDrop) {
        e.target.classList.add('hover-drag-over');
      }
    },
    dragleave(e) {
      if (this.acceptsDrop) {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
        this.timer = null;
        this.totalTime = 2;
        e.target.classList.remove('hover-drag-over');
        this.extendedHover = false;
        // this.$emit('cancel-hover');
      }
    },
    countdown() {
      this.totalTime -= 1;
      if (this.totalTime === 0) {
        this.extendedHover = true;
        console.warn(this);
        this.$emit('long-hover'); //this is the problematic line
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
    .board{
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 200px;
    }
</style>
```

Thanks for any help!

Edit:
the output of the console.log is the following `VueComponent {_uid: 18, _isVue: true, $options: {…}, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: VueComponent, …}` there is some possibility to extend for more information if it is needed too.

Edit2: this component gets generated depending on an array in the parent component like this. So the slot only gets filled with a string for now.

```
<div
                class = "col-4"
                v-for="(device, index) in devices"
                v-bind:key="`device-${device.ip}`"
            >
                <Devices
                :id="`board-${device.ip}`"
                v-bind:class="{'droparea-device':true, 'your-device': (index === thisDeviceIndex)}"
                @dropped-layout="$emit('dropped-layout', $event, index)"
                @long-hover="fetchAvailableUIsForDevice(device.device_name)"
                @cancel-hover="cancelHover()"
                :acceptsDrop=true
                >
                {{device.device_name}}
                </Devices>
            </div>
```

Edit3:
For testing I also just wanted to try a very basic thing. So I added a Button with an on click event like this (but still there are errors):

```
 <b-button
        type="button"
        variant="success"
        v-on:click="$emit('long-hover')"
        >
          Control Center
        </b-button>
```

Comment: And what output from `console.warn(this);`?

Comment: @Anatoly, i added the output to the bottom of the problem description. Does it help like this already?

Comment: Will the issue disappear if you call `this.$emit('long-hover');` in dragenter directly?

Comment: I tested it with this line  **this.timer = setInterval(() => this.$emit('long-hover'), 1000);** and the same error remains. Also I tried getting rid of the timer completely and test it with just **this.$emit('long-hover')** and the error also was still there. Which I find kind of strange...

Comment: Are you sure that the error in THAT $emit call and not about another one?

Comment: I commented out all other appearances ot $emits and the errors still remained, so i think so. Also the error messages showed that the error was found in this component.

Comment: what about a slot? What component do you place in it outside?

Comment: I added the part from the parent component above. It is just a string that is placed in the slot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So thanks for your help witih this strange behavior. After testing the emit with a button and it still not working, I thought that this was very suspicious.
Just to make sure, I took a look into the parent component because there I execute a function when the child emits the event.
When I looked into the function, I had the following line:

```
this.socket.emit('fetch_available_uis', { device_name: device });
```

And here the error description fitted! Because as I said, I included Vuex and after that it didn't work anymore. When adding vuex, I also moved the socket connection to the store so now there was indeed no this.socket or better to say the null value that was mentioned above. 
I fixed this line and the error now is gone!

**So for others with similar problems in the future, I recommend to look at functions in parents that receive your childs event and check for mistakes there. Because even though the error was in the parent, the error messages still showed that the error was found in the child probably because it took the component where the event was emitted as the source and not the component above.**

Comment: Thanks for the posting this answer, got the same error, and there was indeed a property in my parent that was null. Cause of you, I looked at the right place.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I think yes may come from the line as you suggest. `this.countdown` points to nowhere because `this` pointer here is not belongs to Vue

```
this.timer = setInterval(() => this.countdown(), 1000);
```

To fix, I suggest you can try

```
dragenter(e) {
      // on dragenter we start a countdown of 1s
      // over this value --> we see it as a long hover
      console.log('------------dragenter');
      console.log(e);
      let vm = this;  // assign Vue this to vm
      this.timer = setInterval(() => vm.countdown(), 1000); // use vm instead of this
    },
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still the same error if I try it like this, do you have any other idea?

Comment: Also I tried something very basic like adding the emit on a button like I did in other components. I added it to my problem description.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who came here from a reach of  `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'emitsOptions')`

In my case I used the `toRaw()` function and forgot to import it from `vue`:

```
import { toRaw } from 'vue';
```